# SQL syntax with FOREIGN KEY

Tags: sql, foreign-keys, mariadb, create-table

I have the following tables:

```
CREATE TABLE
IF NOT EXISTS {}.roles_permissions
(
role_id INT
(12) NOT NULL,
permission_id INT
(12) NOT NULL,
UNIQUE KEY
(role_id,permission_id)
CONSTRAINT `fk-rprole` FOREIGN KEY
(`role_id`)
REFERENCES `roles`
(`id`)
ON
DELETE CASCADE
ON
UPDATE CASCADE
CONSTRAINT (`fs_rppermission`) FOREIGN KEY
(`permission_id`)
REFERENCES `permissions`
(`id`)
ON
DELETE CASCADE
ON
UPDATE CASCADE
)
```

and it thow a err:- You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'CONSTRAINT `fs_rppermission`
FOREIGN KEY

what's the problem?

Comment: This is a bunch of faqs. Please before considering posting read your textbook and/or manual & google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags; read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. Reflect your research. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table. [ask] Pause work on the overall goal, chop code to the 1st expression not giving what you expect & say what you expect & why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS roles_permissions (
    role_id INT(12) NOT NULL,
    permission_id INT(12) NOT NULL,
    UNIQUE KEY (role_id,permission_id),
    CONSTRAINT `fk-rprole` FOREIGN KEY (`role_id`) 
        REFERENCES `roles`(`id`)
        ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT `fs_rppermission` FOREIGN KEY (`permission_id`)
        REFERENCES `permissions` (`id`)
        ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

Rationale:

- there are missing commas all over your statement
- the name of the foreign should not be surrounded with parentheses
- ... proper formatting makes the statement easier to write and read

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=eacdc0248c032bcbb979322319ab26db)**